# Discord bot is failing to to send a message when a command is used in a reply to a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have written a bot using Python which connects to a Discord community that performs several tasks (logging, kicks and bans, etc.) and all of these functions operate as expected. The only one I am having issues with is when I reply to a message using a command from the bot, it does not send a message to that channel as expected.

Below is the code which is triggering the error:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.command(name='notsupport')
async def not_support(ctx):
    message = ctx.message
    print(message) # Prints the contents of the variable "message".
    if message.reference is not None:
        replied_message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)
        user = replied_message.author
        channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)  # Replace with the channel ID you want to tag
        reply_text = f"{user.mention}, this is not a support channel. Please open a support ticket in {channel.mention}."
        await message.reply(reply_text, mention_author=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please use this command as a reply to someone.")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I have added a print to attempt to print the result of "message" to the console, however it is not returning anything. All other functions are working as expected.

Comment: Your command has no  arguments, it may be the problem?  try something like this:  
 async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

Comment: with @bot.command as a decorator without names, and try to write in the discord chat !test hello

Comment: @DemistheAnacronist the command is not designed to accept arguments. It's intended purpose is to mention the user that is being replied to and post a message. I'll attempt the suggestion regarding no names and report back.

Comment: Why are you also defining an instance of `discord.Client`? Why are you using `intents.messages=True` if `intents.all()` already returns enabled all options?

Comment: Are you invoking your command using `!notsupport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem of intents, which both has to be enabled in the code itself and on the [developer portal](https://discord.com/login?redirect_to=%2Fdevelopers%2Fapplications). I believe the problem here is that you are using both [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.bot) and [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.Client).

Basically, [commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.bot) can do anything [discord.Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.Client) can but not vice versa. There's no need to use them both (you can't either).

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='notsupport')
async def not_support(ctx):
    ...
```

Side note: there is no point in using `discord.Intents.all()` and then enabling specific intents because it enables them all. So I've changed it to `discord.Intents.default`, where only the intents specified below will be enabled (the rest defaulted to False).

Comment: Replacing `@client.event` with `@bot.event` resolved the issue. Thanks for your help!